# how to create table with dynamic column using php

Tags: php

Suppose there is a number of item in array.which may be odd or even like I  have an array which contain item from a to z Now I want to display that item in table . But As you know That There are 23 alphabets I want to display these alphabets in table which contains only 5 column in the last you got only three alphabets I want to display them in table . In the last I want that there should be three column not 5.

Here is my code i could not get that what should i do?

But the problem I faced in the below code is that the second loop is not correct.

```
<?php
$arr=array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h');
$count=  sizeof($arr);
$row=ceil($count/5);
echo "<table border='1'>";
for($r=0;$r<$row;$r++){    
echo "<tr>";
    for($j=0;$j<=5;$j++){
    echo "<td>'".$arr[$j]."'</td>";
    }

echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: you are getting two rows and 6 columns as i tested, now can you tell me what should be expected result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach uses `array_slice` to take out pieces of the source and build rows:

```
$arr=array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h');

$offset = 0; 
$num_columns = 5; //adjust number of columns
$table_html = "<table border='1'>";
while($slice = array_slice($arr,$offset,$num_columns)){
    $offset += $num_columns;
    $row_html = '';
    foreach($slice as $n) $row_html .= "<td>$n</td>";
    $table_html .= "<tr>$row_html</tr>";
}
$table_html .= '</table>';
echo $table_html;
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/ZsO9m)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. Declaring number of column required in a variable, so  which can be changed any time. closing the `tr` tag when loop count is same as number of columns to be displayed.

```
<?php
$arr=array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h');
$columnLength = 5;
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
for($r=0;$r<count($arr) ; $r++){
    echo "<td>'".$arr[$r]."'</td>";
    if($r + 1 ==  $columnLength ) {
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: This does not generate valid table HTML because you have no opening or closing `<tr>` in the second row

Comment: @BeetleJuice, i inspected the elements generated by the code above and second row does have opening and closing `<tr>`.  I liked your approach, but have a doubt. That is can we get desired output by avoiding an extra loop ??

Comment: Hey Sameer :-)  You see all the tags in the browser's DOM inspector because the browser adds the missing tags for you.  Here is what the raw output of your code looks like: https://3v4l.org/g8dK2

Comment: Thank you sir *<tip of the hat>*